# Handling COMError in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, exception, try-except

Running my script, I get the following error for some files:

```
COMError: (-2146822496, None, ('The file appears to be corrupted.', 
'Microsoft Word', 'wdmain11.chm', 25272, None))
```

I have imported **comtypes**, and I wish to do an exception when this error occurs, so I do the following:

```
try:
    code...
except comtypes.COMError:
    pass
```

But it seems that Python does not recognize the exception, as it produces the same COMError as before.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to show some more of your code in order for anyone to help you.  I've run into a similar issue, but my application is a little different.  I'll try my best to assist.

You need to actually handle the error that occurs.
So when you get the exception, you need to do something like this:

assuming this is your error:

COMError: (-2146822496, None, ('The file appears to be corrupted.',  'Microsoft Word', 'wdmain11.chm', 25272, None))

```
except comtypes.COMError as ce:
# get the error information
target_error = ce.args # error in a tuple form
# target_error[0] -> -2146822496
# target_error[1] -> None
# target_error[2] -> 'The file appears to be corrupted.',  'Microsoft Word', 'wdmain11.chm', 25272, None
# target_error[2] is another tuple made up of
# [2][0] -> 'The file appears to be corrupted.'
# [2][1] -> 'Microsoft Word'
# [2][2] -> 'wdmain11.chm'
# [2][3] -> 25272
# [2][4] -> None

if target_error[2][0] == 'The file appears to be corrupted.':
    print("# handle your error here inside this if statement")
```

The point is that once you get the actual error, you can then do something to handle it accordingly.
Again, without seeing your code its difficult to offer any more advice, but you could handle the error based on the Application Type ('Microsoft Word') or the error code ('The file appears to be corrupted.')